# How to remove double quotes inside a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Let's say we have variable x with value "hello world"  (with quotes)

```
string x = @"""hello world""";

string y = ???
```

How to convert x to hello world  (without quotes) and assign it to y ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) passing it a double quote. It would remove double quote from start and end of the string. Like.

```
string y = x.Trim('"');
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the double quotes with an empty string.

```
y = x.Replace( "\"", String.Empty );
```

Comment: This would remove the double quotes inside the text as well. Not really sure if OP needs it.

Comment: Also not sure if the double quotes will always be at the beginning and end of the string. Requirements were very vague. String as presented had them at beginning and end, but didn't have any within the string, so give what we know this answer is just as valid as using Trim().

Comment: @Habib Indeed, but the opposite could be said about your answer. Not sure they don't want all the double quotes removed.

Comment: Exactly. Until we know the parameters both answers are valid as they will produce the exact same result. I didn't say mine was better or worse, I said we don't fully know the requirements and until we do both answers solve the problem. Pointing out additional situations in which they won't work is pointless given what we currently know.

Comment: Craig, I am not saying/downvoting your answer. Your answer is absolutely correct. It is just that we both present a different version and I am only pointing out the the fact that it would remove double quotes inside the text. May be it is an OP requirement may be not. But +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to **remove** the quotes not **escape** them. I corrected the title of your question to reflect that.

If you only want to remove the quotes from the beginning and end of the value, use:

```
string y = x.Trim('"');
```

If you want to remove all quotes wherever they appear in the value, use:

```
string y = x.Replace( "\"", String.Empty );
```

This answer is the same as the same as the ones by Habib and Craig W., but I just grouped them together with the appropriate explanation.

Comment: OP is trying to remove double quotes from the string. Not add it.

Comment: Well, now both of your codes are same, I guess you need `string.Trim` in the first code segment.

Answer (score -1):

use regex to remove all quotes or any characters you wish. eg s/\"//g

UPDATE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = '"""" Hello world """"';
my $y = $x;

$y =~ s/\"//g;

print $y;
```

Comment: To make this an answer rather than a comment, please provide the syntax rather than just the regex. Answers should actually answer the question, not just point in the right direction.

Comment: sorry I thought my example was enough. iv updated my answer with a sample code.